# Facebook in Chrome is showing all options at once

Tags: google-chrome, facebook

I have been using Google Chrome for a while, and it hasn't given me any problems until now. I restarted my computer one day and this is how my Facebook page appeared. It is showing all dropdown options present on the home page, it remains the same on my profile page or any other page.

I am using Google Chrome version 31.0.1650.57. Just for information's sake, I recently installed the *YouTube Downloader* plugin. I have tried disabling it, but it was no use.

[image]

Comment: **Chrome**. Try Ctrl+F5.

Comment: Dude you are awesome.It works. Anyway i figured out that it was the plugin for youtube downloader that was causing the problem in the  first place.